# Bug in C++ (g++) preprocessor with __LINE__ macro?

Tags: c++, boost, g++, preprocessor

I'm encountering a strange behavior of the g++ preprocessor.

I'm using Boost. In file `boost/concept/detail/general.hpp` there is the following macro definition (starting from line 69):

```
#  define BOOST_CONCEPT_ASSERT_FN( ModelFnPtr )              \
    typedef ::boost::concepts::detail::instantiate<          \
    &::boost::concepts::requirement_<ModelFnPtr>::failed>    \
      BOOST_PP_CAT(boost_concept_check,__LINE__)             \   // line 72
      BOOST_ATTRIBUTE_UNUSED
```

which is used by the macro `BOOST_CONCEPT_ASSERT`.

This macro is used in file `boost/algorithm/string/find_format.hpp`:

```
        template< 
            typename OutputIteratorT,
            typename RangeT,
            typename FinderT,
            typename FormatterT>
        inline OutputIteratorT find_format_copy(
            OutputIteratorT Output,
            const RangeT& Input,
            FinderT Finder,
            FormatterT Formatter )
        {
            // Concept check
            BOOST_CONCEPT_ASSERT((    // line 64
                FinderConcept<
                    FinderT,
                    BOOST_STRING_TYPENAME range_const_iterator<RangeT>::type>
                ));
            BOOST_CONCEPT_ASSERT((   // line 69
                FormatterConcept<
                    FormatterT,
                    FinderT,BOOST_STRING_TYPENAME range_const_iterator<RangeT>::type>
                ));
...
```

which gets expanded by the preprocessor to:

```
template<
    typename OutputIteratorT,
    typename RangeT,
    typename FinderT,
    typename FormatterT>
inline OutputIteratorT find_format_copy(
    OutputIteratorT Output,
    const RangeT& Input,
    FinderT Finder,
    FormatterT Formatter )
{
    typedef ::boost::concepts::detail::instantiate<
      &::boost::concepts::requirement_<
      void(*)( FinderConcept< FinderT, 
         typename range_const_iterator<RangeT>::type> )>::failed> 
         boost_concept_check64 __attribute__((__unused__));  // <-- line 64 creates boost_concept_check64 
    typedef ::boost::concepts::detail::instantiate<
      &::boost::concepts::requirement_<
      void(*)( FormatterConcept< FormatterT, FinderT,
         typename range_const_iterator<RangeT>::type> )>::failed>
         boost_concept_check69 __attribute__((__unused__));  // <-- line 69 creates boost_concept_check69
```

Note that in the first usage of `BOOST_CONCEPT_ASSERT`, the `__LINE__` macro gets expanded and creates the identifier `boost_concept_check64`, because the macro was called in `find_format.hpp` in line 64. In the second usage the macro gets expanded to `boost_concept_check69`.

However, when I make some code changes in my project, which are unrelated to the files mentioned above, the macro `BOOST_CONCEPT_ASSERT` gets suddenly expanded differently:

```
template<
    typename OutputIteratorT,
    typename RangeT,
    typename FinderT,
    typename FormatterT>
inline OutputIteratorT find_format_copy(
    OutputIteratorT Output,
    const RangeT& Input,
    FinderT Finder,
    FormatterT Formatter )
{

    typedef ::boost::concepts::detail::instantiate<
        &::boost::concepts::requirement_<
            void(*)
            (
                FinderConcept<
                    FinderT,
                    typename
                    range_const_iterator<RangeT>::type>
                                        )
            >::failed>
    boost_concept_check72  // <-- now __LINE__ is 72
    __attribute__((__unused__))
    ;

    typedef ::boost::concepts::detail::instantiate<
    &::boost::concepts::requirement_<
    void(*)
    (
        FormatterConcept<
        FormatterT,
        FinderT,
        typename
        range_const_iterator<RangeT>::type>
    )
    >::failed>
    boost_concept_check72  // again, __LINE__ is expanded with 72, creating an identical identifier
    __attribute__((__unused__))
```

Now both macros create the identifier `boost_concept_check72`, 72 being the line number of the `__LINE__` statement in the the macro definition of `BOOST_CONCEPT_ASSERT_FN` (see first code exhibit).

Since we have duplicate identifiers, the compiler throws the following error message:

```
In file included from /data/mounts/fedev/sceDev/3rdFeprodVcpkg/2021.05.12/vcpkg-export-20210521-152409/installed/x64-linux/include/boost/concept/assert.hpp:35,
                 from /data/mounts/fedev/sceDev/3rdFeprodVcpkg/2021.05.12/vcpkg-export-20210521-152409/installed/x64-linux/include/boost/concept_check.hpp:20,
                 from /data/mounts/fedev/sceDev/3rdFeprodVcpkg/2021.05.12/vcpkg-export-20210521-152409/installed/x64-linux/include/boost/bimap/detail/bimap_core.hpp:31,
                 from /data/mounts/fedev/sceDev/3rdFeprodVcpkg/2021.05.12/vcpkg-export-20210521-152409/installed/x64-linux/include/boost/bimap/bimap.hpp:61,
                 from /data/mounts/fedev/sceDev/3rdFeprodVcpkg/2021.05.12/vcpkg-export-20210521-152409/installed/x64-linux/include/boost/bimap.hpp:13,
                 from /data/mounts/feactive/local/210827-engine/src/lib/se/util/EnumT.h:2,
                 from /data/mounts/feactive/local/210827-engine/src/lib/se/util/logger.h:4,
                 from /data/mounts/feactive/local/210827-engine/src/lib/se/cluster.h:12,
                 from /local/data/itg/fe/prod/data1/feactive/local/210827-engine/src/lib/se/strategy/hypothetical.cpp:9:
/data/mounts/fedev/sceDev/3rdFeprodVcpkg/2021.05.12/vcpkg-export-20210521-152409/installed/x64-linux/include/boost/concept/detail/general.hpp: In function 'OutputIteratorT boost::algorithm::find_format_copy(OutputIteratorT, const RangeT&, FinderT, FormatterT)':
/data/mounts/fedev/sceDev/3rdFeprodVcpkg/2021.05.12/vcpkg-export-20210521-152409/installed/x64-linux/include/boost/concept/detail/general.hpp:72:20: error: conflicting declaration 'typedef struct boost::concepts::detail::instantiate<(& boost::concepts::requirement_<void (*)(boost::algorithm::FormatterConcept<FormatterT, FinderT, typename boost::range_const_iterator<InputT>::type>)>::failed)> boost_concept_check72'
   72 |       BOOST_PP_CAT(boost_concept_check,__LINE__)             \
      |                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/data/mounts/fedev/sceDev/3rdFeprodVcpkg/2021.05.12/vcpkg-export-20210521-152409/installed/x64-linux/include/boost/concept/detail/general.hpp:72:20: note: previous declaration as 'typedef struct boost::concepts::detail::instantiate<(& boost::concepts::requirement_<void (*)(boost::algorithm::FinderConcept<FinderT, typename boost::range_const_iterator<InputT>::type>)>::failed)> boost_concept_check72
```

This bug is caused by the following change in the code base. I'm highly simplifying the code here. In file `orderInfo.h` we have macro called `DEFINE_CLUSTER_STRUCT`, which uses the Boost preprocessor library `BOOST_PP` to expand the macro into a template declaration.

The overall structure of the macro `DEFINE_CLUSTER_STRUCT` is:

```
DEFINE_CLUSTER_STRUCT(
   <name>,
   (<type1>, <field_name1>, <position_id1>, <options...>)
   (<type2>, <field_name2>, <position_id2>, <options...>)
   ...
)
```

It defines a class `<name>` which contains an arbitrary number of fields.

An example would be

```
DEFINE_CLUSTER_STRUCT
(
   orderInfo,
   (input_type<float_>, price, cluster_id<PRICE>, optional, default_to_zero)
   (input_type<float_>, size, cluster_id<SIZE>, optional, default_to_zero)
)
```

In the code base there are several structs defined using the macro `DEFINE_CLUSTER_STRUCT`. The number of fields vary from 1 to 30.

The compiler error appears when I add another field to the existing definition of `orderInfo`, which currently contains 23 fields. The field definition is simple, valid and should not cause any problems in itself.

The field I'm adding is:

```
(input_type<float_>, newField, cluster_id<NEW_FIELD>, optional)
```

Since we have working struct definitions with more than 24 fields, I doubt that I'm hitting an upper limit for the number of fields.

The file I'm editing does not use Boost concepts, nor can I in any way logically relate it to the error message.

The compiler error occurs in a compilation unit called `hypothetical.cpp` which indirectly includes the definition of `orderInfo` and, through the Boost libraries we're including, also `boost/concept/detail/general.hpp` and `boost/algorithm/string/find_format.hpp`.

I believe that my change in the code base somehow triggers a bug in the g++ preprocessor, because I cannot understand how this change should alter the semantics of the `__LINE__` macro in the Boost header files.

Any ideas on how to proceed here?

Boost version is 1.75, g++ is 10.3.0 on Linux

Comment: Please show a [mre] and include the full gcc and boost versions

Comment: I can't give a better description of the problem. My code changes are unrelated to the files mentioned above. Just looking at the problem description this looks like a bug to me. Why should the value of __LINE__ change, when none of the files are changed?

Comment: If you can produce a [mre] (follow the link for a procedure of how to do this) then maybe we can tell you what in your code is causing the problem

Comment: I've added a schematic description of my code changes which are triggering the error message.

Comment: Still not a [mre]